# SetExpressCheckout occurs a charge with every call?

Tags: paypal

My team is implementing PayPay Express Checkout (NVP) for our website.  Before even initiating a transaction, we would like to perform a 'healthcheck' to confirm PayPal is alive and well.  Looking over the API documentation, there is no obvious 'healthcheck' service available.

We are thinking of using the response from the SetExpressCheckout call to alert us of any system issues.  Are we charged for every SetExpressCheckout call or for only completed transactions?

Making SetExpressCheckout  calls and then abandoning the transaction, is this just going to anger PayPal?

Answer (score 0):

Before we go too far into this, I'd like to mention PayPal APIs are in general quite stable, so such a thing shouldn't be needed at first place.

Having said that, are you seeing too many API failures? If so, I'd rather look into that (contact PayPal support) rather than using SetExpressCheckout as a way to do my own "health checks". Also, I suggest you to subscribe to such notifications at www.paypal-notify.com. This is PayPal website that allows merchants to subscribe for important notifications such as the one you are looking for.

Hope this helps.